# Can a find() on an empty unordered_map lead to an access violation?

Tags: c++, stl, dump, access-violation, unordered-map

I'm investigating a dump, caused by an access violation.
On that particular line of code, there is the following line:

```
if (internal_map.find(uiElemKey) == internal_map.end() || 
    internal_map[uiElemKey].find(m_iPID) == internal_map[uiElemKey].end() || 
    internal_map[uiElemKey][m_iPID].find(idx) == internal_map[uiElemKey][m_iPID].end()) {
```

In the watch-window I can see that the amount of entries in `internal_map` equals 0.

In my opinion, the access violation might be caused by following reasons:

1. As there are no entries in the map, the `find()` method generates an exception.
2. As the are no entries in the map, the `end()` method generates an exception.
3. The `find()` method and the `end()` method are working fine, but give different results, which leads to the following condition, where an access violation happens.

I think that the access violation can be avoided, using this condition:

```
if (internal_map.size() == 0                                              ||
    internal_map.find(uiElemKey) == internal_map.end()                    || 
    internal_map[uiElemKey].find(m_iPID) == internal_map[uiElemKey].end() || 
    internal_map[uiElemKey][m_iPID].find(idx) == internal_map[uiElemKey][m_iPID].end()) {
```

Can somebody confirm this is correct and explain which reason is the correct one?
Thanks in advance

P.s. for your information: I'm doing dump analysis, and it's almost impossible to reproduce the mentioned problem, so just trying and see what happens is not an option.

Comment: No exceptions when calling `find` on empty map. I suspect your map is corrupted before the call.

Comment: Btw, by using iterator returned by `find`, you might avoid repetitive look-ups.

Comment: Look at other internal members might give indication.

Comment: If the map is `empty` can you produce a *complete* `5` line example program that reproduced the error?

Comment: @Galik: it's not that simple: it seems that my map has been modified by other threads, which makes it very difficult to reproduce.

Comment: If you have multiple thread, you should protect your data (`mutex`) to avoid UB by possibly writing and reading the same variable at the same time.

Comment: I had an issue that gave the same impression about the empty map causing the problem. But in my case, it turned out that something else was wrong with my if-statement that surfaced only when the map was empty.

Comment: Does the dump have enough information that you can deduce which part of that expression is triggering the access violation?  Can you tell where the address of the access violation is (e.g., in the `internal_map`, the `uiElemKey`, the code)?  Does the code overload the hash function for your key type and could the exception be happening there?  Does the access violation happen on a read or a write operation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that the unordered map is not being modified by some other thread when  `find()` is executing, there is no chance that `find()` or `end()` will throw an exception or crash. Their behavior is defined for empty container. So there is no way to corrupt the map by just calling them. Saying this, your test for `size()` is redundant.

Comment: That was also my idea: launching `find()` or `end()` does not cause an access violation. But if both methods give different results, then the map gets accessed (`internal_map[uiElemKey]`) and I'm afraid that this might cause an access violation. Do you think that is possible?

Comment: @Dominique Before accessing `internal_map[uiElemKey]` you have already checked that `uiElemKey` exists. I can't see any reason for them to generate access violation.

Comment: @Dominique the order of evaluation for `&&` `||` operators are also defined.

Comment: That's exactly my problem: I've executed a `find(uiElemKey)` and I have checked if this equals the `end()` method. As mentioned in some examples on the web, this way of working is working correctly (but all the examples are treating maps which are not empty). I just want to be sure that, in case of an empty map, the result of `find(anything)` and `end()` are also equal.

Comment: @Dominique yes they are also equal for empty containers. Whenever a key is not present it will return `end()`. Whether the container is empty or not doesn't matter.

Comment: @Dominique: The single solution to make an object safe to access from multiple threads is `std::mutex`. That's not just for threads altering an object, even the reader threads need it.

Answer (score 2):

> As there are no entries in the map, the find() method generates an
>   exception

No, if your program is valid (there is no UB somewhere earlier) [`find()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/find) method will return past-the-end iterator which equals to iterator returned by `end()` in the same line of code.